# Windows C++11 DLL: Define DLL interface in abstract class

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I jave the following interface that must be implemented by a set of DLL libraries I want to dynamically import later:

```
class ToolboxInterface {

public:

struct ToolboxInfo {
    std::string name;
};

virtual void process() = 0;
virtual void clear() = 0;

};
```

I want to dynamically load the DLL's as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696653/dynamically-load-a-function-from-a-dll), and for that reason I have to force this interface to all my DLLs, as a way of being sure I can use `GetProcAddress` in all DLL's.

What is the best way of forcing this interface into a DLL project? SHould I not use a class and use some other strategy instead? Or how can I use the class interface?

Comment: Write an in-process COM DLL.

Comment: @RichardCritten thank you. could you please ellaborate?

Comment: It is not a good idea to use C++ classes as plugin interface unless you can guarantee all the components are built with the same compiler with same settings. Use of C++ standard library classes in interface unfortunately is especially tricky due to its template implementation - not only runtime used should match but even minor additional define like [_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh697468.aspx) may break binary compatibility.

Comment: @frymode thanks that's a good point. So should I just keep standard C function reference?