# Export information from a dll and create an instance of the class

Tags: c++, class, dll, export

I have a DLL in which I know the functions implemented and the classes names.
However, I don't know much more.
I would like to create an object from this class in the DLL and use the methods.
How can I perform this?
I successfully get function from this dll with the following example:

```
typedef int (__stdcall *f_dll)();
std::string filename = "C:\\Test.dll";
std::wstring tmp = s2ws(filename);
HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary(tmp.c_str());

if (!hGetProcIDDLL)
{
    std::cerr << "Failed to load DLL" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

// resolve function address here
f_dll func = (f_dll)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "function");
if (!func)
{
    std::cout << "Failed to load function inside DLL" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends, what dou you know -if you have header file you may look: [Dynamically load a function from a DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696653/dynamically-load-a-function-from-a-dll)
Maybe, the header of function is incorrect. L

If you don't have header you may use nm (tool from gcc), but it works only on files compiled by gcc-family. You should get some symbols if they are provided for debugging, which contain

Comment: I do not know the headers unfortunately. I will check nm but I am coding on windows... Hope it is compatible