# Trying to communicate with Hamamatsu Micro Spectrometer

Tags: c++, communication

I'm trying to communicate with a Micro Spectrometer, I have it's .dll (not .h file).
I have all the function names that I need but the code can't find them.

The code is VERY basic because I want to check initialisation first.

My question is, how do I call function from the dll file?

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include <Windows.h>


int main()
{

    HINSTANCE hGetProcID = LoadLibrary("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Ham\\EvaluationSoftware\\MICROMODULE_USB2.dll");

    int n1, n2 = 0;
    unsigned short num = 0;
    char arr = {};


    n1 = MICROMODULE_USB2_initialize();
    //n2 = MICROMODULE_USB2_getModuleConnectionList(arr, num);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How should a compiler know what `MICROMODULE_USB2_initialize` is? If you were a compiler, what code would you generate for this call?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8696688/4468078