# Dynamically use a DLL from a console application

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dllexport

I'm trying to create a library `Lib.dll` to get dynamically called from a console application but cannot find the function `funci()` I want to call.

The `Lib.dll` is the outcome of a project (Console Application,  but set to Configuration Type: .dll) created in Visual Studio 2019.

`Lib.cpp` is the only file in that project, and only contains the code:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int funci() 
{
    return 50;
}
```

I think I'm exporting the function correctly as I found the function by using [DLL Export Viewer v1.66](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html).

[image]

However, I struggle to locate the function through my Console Application (.exe):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

typedef int(__cdecl* o_funci)(void);

o_funci funci;

int main()
{
    HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibraryA("C:\\Lib.dll");

    if (!hGetProcIDDLL) {
        std::cout << "could not load the dynamic library" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // resolve function address here
    funci = (o_funci) GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "funci");
    if (!funci) {
        std::cout << "could not locate the function" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::cout << "funci() returned " << funci() << std::endl;

    FreeLibrary(hGetProcIDDLL);
}
```

Something is going wrong at `GetProcAddress` but don't know why. Where did I go wrong?

Output:

[image]

I've been looking at this old post: [Dynamically load a function from a DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696653/dynamically-load-a-function-from-a-dll)

---

**EDIT: SOLVED THANKS TO tenfour**

I used DependencyWalker.

Without `extern "C"` I could see the undecorated `funci` had the name `?funci@@YGHXZ`,

[image]

So `funci = (o_funci)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "?funci@@YGHXZ");` worked.

With `extern "C"` the undecorated `funci` had the name `_funci@0` - a little cleaner.

[image]

Another note; using ordinal `0x0001` worked in both cases. Like this: `funci = (o_funci)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, (PCSTR)0x0001);`

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tool you're using is showing you a pretty-fied version of the export name. Its real name will include name mangling, which is a convoluted attempt to embed call info into the export name.

You have a number of options to make this work with `GetProcAddress`:

1. Use the REAL export name. Your tool probably has the option to see the un-prettyfied name (the mangled export name)
2. Export the function using a module definition file (*.def), where you can even specify the name it will be exported as
3. Import by ordinal instead of name
4. Wrap the function in `extern "C" { ... }` which will use C-style naming, which avoids name mangling.

The most common solution is probably #4, with #2 as a close second.

Comment: WTF? I missed the `extern "C"` but looked at the snapshot of OP and thought: Hmm. `__cdecl` might fix it but I don't have experience with it. I never had guessed that the DLL export viewer shows _a pretty-fied version of the export name_ (I've some experience with DependencyWalker but I cannot remember how it is done there.) How underhanded...

Comment: @Scheff "_I've some experience with DependencyWalker but I cannot remember how it is done there._" Dependecy Walker has a toggle named "Undecorate C++ functions".

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Correct, confirmed. ;-) I'm not sure whether this can be configured (or is remembered somehow) but in my case the "true" (decorated) names are shown by default. That's what I would consider as "less underhanded". (Dep.Walker still rocks.) :-)

Comment: I used DependencyWalker. Without `extern "C"` I could see the undecorated `funci` had the name `?funci@@YGHXZ`, so `funci = (o_funci)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "?funci@@YGHXZ");` worked. 

With `extern "C"` the undecorated `funci` had the name `_funci@0` - a little cleaner. 

Using ordinal `0x0001` worked in both cases: `funci = (o_funci)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, (PCSTR)0x0001);` 

Is it a better idea to use ordinal in general? 

Thank you @tenfour

Comment: `extern "C"` doesn't avoid name mangling. It merely chooses a different set of name decorations, that are easier to read and type. There's also a 5th option: Compile a 64-bit binary (with `extern "C"`). The name decoration in this case will disappear.

Comment: @jub: Importing by ordinal requires that you *never* change the order of exports. A pretty tough requirement to satisfy, and hardly justifiable if all you need is more convenient important names.

Comment: [Use a `.def` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-def-files?view=vs-2019) to control the exact formatting of the exported name.  Then you can remove all of the decoration and just export `funci` and have it map internally to `?funci@@YGHXZ` or `_funci@0` as needed