# Call Function in DLL from C++ Program?

Tags: c++, dll

I'm attempting to call a function inside a shared library DLL file using a C++ program. I'm using C++ 17 for all files in question.

The DLL file in question was compiled from the following C++ file called `test.cpp`, containing a single function called `test`:

```
#include <iostream>

int test()
{
    std::cout << "test\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with the following Visual Studio 2022 Native Command Prompt command:

```
cl.exe /LD test.cpp
```

Which provides me with a DLL file called `test.dll`.

I now want to call the `test` function inside the DLL file. I used the [following post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696653/dynamically-load-a-function-from-a-dll) and [the official `GetProcAddress` function documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress) to write a program for loading functions from a DLL file as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>

std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> StringConverter;
typedef int(__stdcall* DLLFx)();

std::string GetWorkingDir()
{
    TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);
    std::wstring::size_type pos = std::wstring(buffer).find_last_of(L"\\/");

    return StringConverter.to_bytes(std::wstring(buffer).substr(0, pos).c_str()) + "\\";
}

bool LoadDLLFunction(std::string libPath, std::string fxName)
{
    HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary((WCHAR*)StringConverter.from_bytes(libPath.c_str()).data());

    if (!hGetProcIDDLL)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Could not locate DLL file\"" + libPath + "\"!\n";

        return false;
    }

    DLLFx fx = (DLLFx)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, (CHAR*)StringConverter.from_bytes(fxName.c_str()).data());

    if (!fx)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Could not locate function \"" + fxName + "\" in DLL file \"" + libPath + "\"!\n";

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    std::string workDir = GetWorkingDir();
    bool result = LoadDLLFunction(workDir + "test.dll", "test");

    if (result)
    {
        std::cout << "Result of loaded DLL function call: " << DLLFx() << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "\n";

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Where:

- The global variable `StringConverter` is the converter for converting the regular `std::string` to the `std::wstring` types that many Windows API functions accept (deprecated in C++ 17 and later).
- The global variable `DLLFx` is the pointer to the loaded function from the DLL.
- The function `GetWorkingDir` serves for acquiring the current working directory of the program.
- The function `LoadDLLFunction` serves for loading a function from a DLL file.

I then simply attempt to call the loaded function, and display the returned result (which should just be a 0, and a `test` string printed to the console as per the definition of the `test` function in the loaded DLL).

The issue is the fact that the program above finds & loads the DLL, but fails to load the function inside the DLL, resultant printed console message always being `ERROR: Could not locate function "test" in DLL file "test.dll"!`.

One of the possible issues I imagined could be causing a problem is the string conversions when passing the paths of the DLL file and/or the name of the DLL function, where I pass the two with `WCHAR*` and `CHAR*` types respectivelly. Those two appear to represent `wchar_t` and `char` respectivelly, which should be the types of the two strings I'm passing, but I could be missing some underlying string mechanics that are taking place here.

What am I missing here? What is the proper way to load & call a DLL function from a C++ program?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

---

### **ATTEMPTS EDIT**

According to some of the comment suggestions on this post and another forum, I went ahead and carried out some further tests to see if I could figure out what's wrong here;

To try out some suggestions, I first changed my `test.cpp` file that gets compiled to a DLL according to several sugggestions (adding the `extern "C"` and `__declspec(dllexport)` designations), as such:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

extern "C"
{
    int __declspec(dllexport) test()
    {
        std::cout << "test\n";
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Which I then compiled to `test.dll`, and ran a `dumpbin /exports test.dll` command, resulting in the following output:

```
Dump of file test.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for test.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    FFFFFFFF time date stamp
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           1 number of functions
           1 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00001180 test

  Summary

        3000 .data
        3000 .pdata
       12000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
       23000 .text
        1000 _RDATA
```

Given the presence of a `test` in the console output above, I was hopeful that the function would now be callable.

Unfortunately, my program still fails to locate the `test` function inside the DLL...

I also tried to simplify the function name argument supplied to `GetProcAddress` by just doing `fxName.c_str()` instead of `(CHAR*)StringConverter.from_bytes(fxName.c_str()).data()`, to no avail.

I also tried changing the name of the `test` function to something other than the filename, `test_fx` for example, yet it still remained undiscovered by my program.

I will try and get the Dependencies tool working and check the DLL through that, however given that I can see `test` when I use the `dumpbin` command, I'm assuming that the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Are you forgetting to export the function `test` by using `__declspec(dllexport)` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-declspec-dllexport?view=msvc-170). You can use a program like Dependency Walker to see if a function is exported or not

Comment: Your problem might be [Name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling), making the internal name not being just "test". The compiler must consider overloading when generating code for functions.

Comment: Also, `GetProcAddress` accepts ASCII strings only. There is no Unicode version of it.

Comment: Your code seems overly complex. `DLLFx fx = (DLLFx)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, fxName.c_str();` should work for you, assuming `hGetProcIDDLL` is a valid handle, of course.

Comment: Functions are not available for `GetProcAddress` by default: names must be explicitly exported from a DLL. This can be done by annotating the function with `__declspec(dllexport)`, or by writing a [.DEF file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/module-definition-dot-def-files) and passing it to the linker, or with [/EXPORT option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/export-exports-a-function) on the linker command line.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions; I edited the post to include some of the attempts regarding your comments. From what I can tell, the issue still remains, where the function inside the DLL cannot be found by `GetProcAddress`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I finally figured it out.

I realized that my major oversight here was the fact that I was calling the `DLLFx` **type** in the `main` function's final print statement, not a **function of that type**... Unfortunate oversight on my part.

There were other things that people pointed out, such as the method of converting the `libName` and `fxName` string arguments to the types accepted by `LoadLibrarW` and `GetProcAddress`, and the use of `__declspec(dllexport)` and `__declspec(dllimport)` in the DLL and client respectivelly.

The following full code now produces the desired results:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>

std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> StringConverter;
typedef int __declspec(dllimport) (__stdcall* DLLFx)(void);
DLLFx FX;

std::string GetWorkingDir()
{
    TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);
    std::wstring::size_type pos = std::wstring(buffer).find_last_of(L"\\/");

    return StringConverter.to_bytes(std::wstring(buffer).substr(0, pos).c_str()) + "\\";
}

bool LoadDLLFunction(std::string libPath, std::string fxName)
{
    std::wstring libPathWide = StringConverter.from_bytes(libPath);

    HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibraryW(libPathWide.c_str());

    if (!hGetProcIDDLL)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Could not locate DLL file\"" + libPath + "\"!\n";

        return false;
    }

    FX = (DLLFx)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, fxName.c_str());

    if (!FX)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Could not locate function \"" + fxName + "\" in DLL file \"" + libPath + "\"!\n";

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    std::string workDir = GetWorkingDir();
    bool result = LoadDLLFunction(workDir + "test.dll", "test_fx");

    if (result)
        std::cout << "Result of loaded DLL function call: " << FX() << "\n";

    std::cout << "\n";

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Alongside the following code compiled into `test.dll`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall test_fx(void)
{
    std::cout << "test\n";
    return 1;
}
```

Thanks for all the comments!