# Why does my D2XX application not work when forked?

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, daemon, d2xx

I'm writing a simple application in C, running on a Raspberry Pi, that makes use of the [D2XX drivers](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm) to communicate with a serial port device. I've followed a number of online tutorials and reference guides to get it working, and have taken steps such as setting up custom udev rules to ensure the drivers can load properly, I followed FTDI's build instructions to install the shared library, I use the `-l` argument of gcc to link in the library when compiling, and I run my C program with `sudo` to ensure the drivers have proper access. And that has been a success! The program works as intended.

Now I am trying to convert my simple program into a daemon process that can be controlled with an init.d script (a la `service start`), and have run into trouble.

For simplicity's sake, here is a watered down version of my C program which **does work**:

***myprog.c:***

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ftd2xx.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DWORD i, iNumDevs = 0;
    char *serialNumber = malloc(64);
    FT_STATUS ftStatus = FT_CreateDeviceInfoList(&iNumDevs);
    for (i = 0; i < iNumDevs; i++) {
        ftStatus = FT_ListDevices((PVOID)i, serialNumber, FT_LIST_BY_INDEX|FT_OPEN_BY_SERIAL_NUMBER);
        if (FT_OK == ftStatus) {
            break;
        }
    }

    // more code here...

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I compile that with `gcc -lftd2xx -o myprog myprog.c` and then run it with `sudo ./myprog`, and take my word for it that it does everything that it's supposed to do. But now that I am trying to re-work this same code into a daemon, I've been following some other online tutorials, and the code above has been transformed into something that looks more like this. Currently, this **does not work:**

***mydaemon.c:***

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "ftd2xx.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid, sid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (pid > 0) {
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    umask(0);
    openlog("mydaemon", LOG_PID|LOG_CONS, LOG_USER);

    sid = setsid();
    if (sid < 0) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "Failed to set session ID on child process");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if ((chdir("/")) < 0) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "Failed to change working directory");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    close(STDIN_FILENO);
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(STDERR_FILENO);

    while (1) {

        DWORD i, iNumDevs = 0;
        char *serialNumber = malloc(64);

        syslog(LOG_INFO, "I get to this line");
        FT_STATUS ftStatus = FT_CreateDeviceInfoList(&iNumDevs);
        syslog(LOG_INFO, "I do not get to this line :( ");

        // more code here...

        sleep(10);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I compile that program in the exact same way: `gcc -lftd2xx -o mydaemon mydaemon.c`; I run it the same way: `sudo ./mydaemon`, but unfortunately it does not work. In a separate console window I'm tailing the `/var/log/messages` file, and I can clearly see it reach my first log message (i.e. "I can get to this line"), but immediately after that it is dead in the water. I never see the second log message, and indeed, at that point the program becomes totally unresponsive. I have to find its process ID and kill it.

In other words, as soon as it tries to make a call to the D2XX drivers in the forked process, it fails. What am I doing wrong? I've already demonstrated with the first example that the code *does work*, so what is it about running as a daemon that causes it to completely break down? As far as I can tell it doesn't even get a chance to execute the D2XX method in question; it's as if it simply can't find the method in the first place, while running in the forked process.

Comment: I've been doing some research on this problem and decided to try linking the static library rather than the dynamic one. To do so I had to change my compile command to `gcc -o mydaemon mydaemon.c /usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.a -lpthread -Wl,--no-as-needed -ldl` Unfortunately, that did not work either. It compiled, but ultimately it still ran into exactly the same issue.

Comment: UPDATE: Apparently if I use `vfork` instead of `fork` then it works. The only problem is that the parent process doesn't automatically terminate when you use `vfork`. I can go ahead and manually kill it, and the child process continues to run, and continues to successfully access the D2XX functions. However I would really prefer to get this working with regular `fork`... I'd rather not write scripts to kill the parent every time as that seems like a cheap workaround. I'd rather figure out what the root issue is and address that in code.

Comment: It would probably help if you `strace` the program (using the `-f` option to follow forks) to see where it gets stuck.

Comment: Also, while it's not obviously the problem here, it's not always a good idea to just close `std{in,out,err}` without replacing them with something. Even if your program does nothing with them, some libraries may assume that they're there for various purposes (even if they shouldn't). Certainly, if this `libftd2xx` is one of those poorly written libraries that spit out spurious messages on `stderr` (I've no experience with it myself), then that could be the source of much trouble.

Comment: Also, while I too would like to see why the program fails, I'd just like to mention that it's usually a better idea to do initialization of this kind *before* you fork and daemonize. Daemonizing programs are much nicer to deal with if they only exit with `EXIT_SUCCESS` only when all their initialization has properly succeeded and they're ready to actually do their task.

Comment: [This is a known issue with libftd2xx](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35186414/149341).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because it uses `libusb`... and they appear to do it badly.

See my question here: [libusb-1.0 hotplug events stop working in parent after fork(), when child calls libusb_exit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42145020/libusb-1-0-hotplug-events-stop-working-in-parent-after-fork-when-child-calls)

And the discussion here: https://github.com/libusb/libusb/issues/268

My specific problem was related to hotplug events, but I expect that other things will go wrong for you too.

The reason that this is less obvious in your scenario is because they are probably doing some setup / init when the library loads (how kind of them), rather than when you start to use it.

As pointed out by @duskwuff, there is another answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35186414/149341

---

I've just done some playing, follow along below:

```sh
cd $(mktemp -d)
curl http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX/Linux/libftd2xx-x86_64-1.3.6.tgz | tar -xvz
```

Put this in `test.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ftd2xx.h"

int main(void) {
    int num_devs;

    fprintf(stderr, "in to main()\n");

    FT_STATUS ft_status = FT_CreateDeviceInfoList(&num_devs);
    fprintf(stderr, "FT_CreateDeviceInfoList() returned: %d\n", ft_status);

    fprintf(stderr, "out of main()\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```sh
gcc test.c -o test -g -I release -L release/build -lftd2xx -ldl -lpthread
```

Now in `gdb`:

```
[...]
Reading symbols from test...done.
(gdb) b libusb_init
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40cd20
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 2 at 0x401d75: file test.c, line 7.
Starting program: /tmp/tmp.jJpBNywVzB/test 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, 0x000000000040cd20 in libusb_init ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000040cd20 in libusb_init ()
#1  0x0000000000401f36 in my_init ()
#2  0x000000000041a05d in __libc_csu_init ()
#3  0x00007ffff7614ed5 in __libc_start_main (main=0x401d6d <main>, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe228, init=0x41a010 <__libc_csu_init>, fini=<optimised out>, rtld_fini=<optimised out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffe218)
    at libc-start.c:246
#4  0x0000000000401ca9 in _start ()
(gdb)
```

It hit the breakpoint on `libusb_init()` before even getting to `main()`, called from their `my_init()`.