# How to build a qt application (not shared lib) that links dynamically on Linux

Tags: linux, qt, shared-libraries

I want to build a qt app that links with shared libraries (as qt apps do by default). But qt always compiles the app as a shared library. I know that this is possible because I've found several Linux apps (not shared libraries) that links dynamically. For example, most of KDE applications are written in Qt, but are still applications, not shared libs.
Is there a compiler/linker flag that allows me to build qt **applications** on Linux? No answer `-static`, please.

Comment: probably this will solve your problem --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626526/load-shared-library-by-path-at-runtime

Comment: Thanks for reply, but no. My app links well with dynamic libs, but qt compiles it as a shared library. As my problem is specific to Qt, I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are **not** shared libraries, but normal applications.

On modern GNU/Linux systems, programs are compiled as **PIE** (Position Indipendent Executable). This is done, for security reasons, to allow the `text` section of the program (i.e. the code) to be loaded at a new random address every time the program is run.

From an ELF/kernel perspective the process loading a PIE program is extremely similar to the process of loading a PIC shared library, so a PIE executable has ELF type `ET_DYN`, which is the one used by shared libraries.

For this reason, some programs, like `file(1)`, will recognize them as shared libraries, but they are **not** shared libraries.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. KDE team should do something with that.