# Can the RESTful API be started via a '.dll' file?

Tags: c++, rest

I am currently developing cpp backend and js webapp. I want to use the backend as a REST API. Normally I use REST API as executable file, so when I run the file the REST API starts serving. Here's my question: Can I use and launch REST api without executable? Can I create the REST API as a dll and import it from somewhere else and launch it?

I am inexperienced in these matters. Please help me out.

Comment: Why would you even want to do that? You now have a seperate executable, if that crashes it can easily be restarted, if there are bugs code cannot "escape" into other code not under your control. So making it a dll would be bad for quality and security reasons.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I am working ona a self contained solution and i got some restrictions about the task so i had to. do you think is there any way ?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626526/load-shared-library-by-path-at-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626526/load-shared-library-by-path-at-runtime) yes but very complicate.

Comment: If memory serves, Microsoft IIS (internet Information Server) allows you to write extensions as DLLs. I doubt it makes sense for a simple RESTful API (I'd expect IIS can handle that pretty easily out of the box) but if you wanted to do it in an extension, you probably could. There would still be an executable involved though--just not one somebody else wrote instead of you.

Comment: "import it from somewhere else" what's the somewhere else? any process you load the dll in, or just those that are expecting it to provide a REST api?

Comment: @Caleth I will use it in JS but I want to start REST API in cpp. That's why I'm looking.

Comment: What cpp process will be loading this dll?